# How can a directory with wide open permissions throw an EPERM error (hadoop)?

Tags: hadoop, file-permissions, hdfs

I've mounted my own ext4 disk ont /mnt/sdb and chmodded it to 777.

However, when starting the data node:

/etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-datanode start

I get the following error in my logs (bottom of this message)

---

What is the EPERM error caused by, and how can I reproduce it?  I'm assuming that, since the directory permissions are recursively set to 777 there shouldnt be a way that this error could occur, unless somewhere intermittently the directory permissions are being changed by hdfs to the wrong thing.

---

```
2013-07-06 15:54:13,968 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Invalid dfs.datanode.data.dir /mnt/sdb/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/data :
EPERM: Operation not permitted
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO.chmod(Native Method)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:605)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:439)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:138)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:154)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.getDataDirsFromURIs(DataNode.java:1659)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1638)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1575)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1598)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1751)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1772)
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `ls -l /mnt/sdb/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/data` back into your original question.

Comment: I can't reproduce this because I've changed my VM disk setup since posting and went with another approach. Just for some color the way I arrived at it was that I mounted a new disk device on my VM, and changed the dfs.data.dir property to point to that directory.  After the change, the EPERM error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard Linux behavior. When attempting to chmod, its not the permissions that matter but the user attempting it. The thread at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52519/when-does-chmod-fail answers further on this.